# how to send object/database connection to function in php

Tags: php

i open a sql connection and try to send it to another function and it doesnt work . 
its probbably something with sintax , 
i search all over the internet and couldnt find it .

my code :

```
$mainDataBase = mysqli_connect(/...../);

if ($mainDataBase->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mainDataBase->connect_error);
    die;
}

/**
 * 1 -> logIn && getInformation
 * 
 * */

switch ($whichOperation){
case 1:
    $gettingPlayerNumber = checkIfPlayerExist($mainDataBase, $playerName, $playerPass);
    if($gettingPlayerNumber == 0){
        echo "F";
        die;
    }
    ... keep going ...
```

function ::

```
function checkIfPlayerExist($dataBase ,$playerName ,$pass ){

    $result = $dataBase->query("select playerNumber from PlayerInformation where (playerAccount = '" . $playerName ."') && (playerPass = " . $playerPass .")");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if($row != null)
        return $row['playerNumber'];
    return 0;
}
```

its says:

Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object.

thank you for your time.

- after some of the answer i checked and $result is null , but i checked the query before and now and it works!. 
  pass is int so it doesnt need any '' around it in the query.*

*its connected succsesfully to the database - i checked this too*

Comment: is var_dump($dataBase) inside checkIfPlayerExist() null?

Comment: Check the query error after the query. It is telling you that $result is not an object, so you cannot fetch anything. Therefore, $result is likely holding an error.

Comment: brackets are used for subqueries. 9 times out of 10, removing them solves it.

Comment: Your code may contain syntax errors. 
Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: *Woaaahhh there cowboy* - `$mainDataBase = mysqli_connect(/...../);` and `$dataBase`? Error reporting would have spotted that. In conjunction with what I said about subqueries. Sure hope you're reading comments and not just answers below.

Comment: its connected succesfully to the data base..

Comment: either way, check for errors, which I already stated above. You're not doing that and just letting your server take care of the minimum checking.

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be a bug in your query,near password,missing quotes:

change,

```
 $result = $dataBase->query("select playerNumber from PlayerInformation where (playerAccount = '" . $playerName ."') && (playerPass = " . $playerPass .")");
```

to

```
 $result = $dataBase->query("select playerNumber from PlayerInformation where (playerAccount = '" . $playerName ."') && (playerPass = '" . $playerPass ."')");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but my pas is always a int it cannot be char and its define as int , and i check my sql before i came here , i didnt down vote you